# Need help writing Java simple DNS client with specific DNS server

Tags: java, dns, udp

I'm a CS student working on a Java DNS resolver client assignment. My DNS resolver must accept as input a DNS root server IP and a domain name. Then the program must query the DNS root server given by the user, and iteratively query any intermediate servers (which I understand will be found in "the Authority and Additional Information sections" of the reply) until I have come across the IP of the domain entered by the user. I understand that the information I am looking for is found in the RR but I am stuck on querying a specific DNS root server as well as how to get the RR in order to proceed from there. I have looked around but have not had much luck with finding any guidance to do this in Java using the standard libraries **I cannot use any DNS library (DNSQuery, SimpleResolver, etc).** I am hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

This is an example of what I have to do :

```
>java dns_resolver 202.12.27.33 cs.poly.edu
DNS server to query: 202.12.27.33
Reply received. Content overview:
    0 Answers
    6 Intermediate Name Servers
    7 Additional Information Records
Answers section:
Authoritative Section:
    Name: edu Name Server: l.edu-servers.net
    Name: edu Name Server: a.edu-servers.net
    Name: edu Name Server: f.edu-servers.net
    Name: edu Name Server: c.edu-servers.net
Additional Information Section:
. . .

until I reach 1 in the Answer section containing the IP of the domain entered by the user.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the difficulty in the assignment is in implementing the DNS protocol yourself (otherwise you'd be able to use SimpleResolver, etc).  Here's a page with details of the DNS protocol:  [RFC 1035 §4.1](http://www.freesoft.org/CIE/RFC/1035/39.htm). Use that as a guide to build the request, then use java socket I/O to send the request and receive the response.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've looked through the RFC before making this post but I am stuck on the part of using a user inputted DNS server IP. The Java DatagramSocket class requires a port number with the InetAddress but I don't have a port number. The user will just input the IP address.

Comment: Use port 53.  That's the standard DNS port.
See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers